# сделать привязку к системной дате и времени? с++

Tags: c++, дата, время

подскажите как сделать привязку класса к системной дате и времени?

Мне необходимо чтобы данные бэкапились в структуру в зависимости от дня недели, после чего к ним можно было бы иметь доступ.

Не могу понять как сделать привязку чтобы бэкапилось по дням, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Почитайте [эту](https://prog-cpp.ru/c-time-date/) статью.

Comment: Получить текущую дату/время? Или что в вашем понимании "привязка"? посмотрите это - https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime

Comment: какие данные, в какую структуру, что в вашем понимании бэкапились, что такое привязка?

Answer (score -1):

текущее время в текущей системе

```
time_t now = time(0);
```

конверт в строку

```
char* dt = ctime(&now);
```

вывод

```
cout << "Дата и время: " << dt << endl;
```

Вывод->
Дата и время: Tus Jun  11 10:35:41 2020